# Find the frequency of a true value in a vector

Tags: r, vector, frequency, logical-operators

I have a vector with 100 values, ranging from 0 to 100
What can I do if i want to find the frequency that numbers bigger than 95 (>95) appear?

I have tried the table() (no luck there) and found out by testing the frequency() has nothing to do with what im looking for.
Any ideas?

Comment: Let's call your vector `x`. Then: `answer = sum(x > 95)`.

Comment: Do you mean the number of elements that are greater than 95; or considering only values greater than 95, how frequently did each occur?

Comment: What @ulfelder said. For the frequency `sum(x > 95)/length(x)`.

Comment: @nicola isnt the sum/length the propability tho?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't meet the minimum-character limit for answers.

Comment: @ulfelder Ill ask you the same question I did to nicola, is there a difference between the probability and the frequency?

Comment: Only you know what stat you want, but frequency is conventionally defined as a rate or proportion, which here is functionally the same as the probability of drawing that answer at random. So @nicola's addition would give you that.

Comment: There is a huge difference between frequency and probability. They are different concepts. I guess SO is not the right place to discuss this.

Comment: @nicola its just that I just read my next task and it wants me to find the probability, but I only come up with the same result. Did I missunderstand something?

Comment: For nicola's comment.  `mean(x > 95)` is perhaps an easier alternative, particularly if there are missing values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vector x. Then the answer = sum(x > 95)/length(x)

Added it since the response in the comments was never made into a proper answer.